# Print Group Title of ER OG Reference field

Tags: views, entities, organic-groups

I've got a flag with a form. One field is an Entity Refernce, OG Reference that allows the flagging user to select one of the "teams" the user is group member.

I want to rewrite the field.tpl.php to show not just the team name but also the group's title it belongs to.

All this in a view. So I have to use the content of the field to get the group it belongs to.